# Convert excel to pdf java

Tags: java, excel, itext

I have an excel and I want to convert it to pdf. I already use iText but it's  not efficient because I have many excel templates and with iText I use Iterator to create pdf which means I have to change my code every time I change my excel. Is there any other way to convert excel to pdf? Any library?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Apache POI API
here is an example:

```
   public class excel2pdf {  
            public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
                    //First we read the Excel file in binary format into FileInputStream
                    FileInputStream input_document = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\excel_to_pdf.xls"));
                    // Read workbook into HSSFWorkbook
                    HSSFWorkbook my_xls_workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(input_document); 
                    // Read worksheet into HSSFSheet
                    HSSFSheet my_worksheet = my_xls_workbook.getSheetAt(0); 
                    // To iterate over the rows
                    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = my_worksheet.iterator();
                    //We will create output PDF document objects at this point
                    Document iText_xls_2_pdf = new Document();
                    PdfWriter.getInstance(iText_xls_2_pdf, new FileOutputStream("Excel2PDF_Output.pdf"));
                    iText_xls_2_pdf.open();
                    //Suppose we have two columns in the Excel sheet, so we create a PDF table with two columns
                    //Note: There are ways to make this dynamic in nature, if you want to.
                    PdfPTable my_table = new PdfPTable(2);
                    //We will use the object below to dynamically add new data to the table
                    PdfPCell table_cell;
                    //Loop through rows.
                    while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                            Row row = rowIterator.next(); 
                            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                                    while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                                            Cell cell = cellIterator.next(); //Fetch CELL
                                            switch(cell.getCellType()) { //Identify CELL type
                                                    //you need to add more code here based on
                                                    //your requirement / transformations
                                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                                    //Push the data from Excel to PDF Cell
                                                     table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cell.getStringCellValue()));
                                                     //feel free to move the code below to suit to your needs
                                                     my_table.addCell(table_cell);
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                            //next line
                                    }

                    }
                    //Finally add the table to PDF document
                    iText_xls_2_pdf.add(my_table);                       
                    iText_xls_2_pdf.close();                
                    //we created our pdf file..
                    input_document.close(); //close xls
            }
    }
```

Comment: did you read my question?? this example doesn't work for every excel. My table is deformed

Comment: Can you add your excel dump

Comment: no, I can't add it. But I can say that when on excel a text has 2 cells the iterator adds me 2 cells (1 with the text and another empty

Comment: @manuel_k can you create a dummy excel with different fields(as you don't want to show me your original excel),  so can you please add a dummy excel with the same problem

Comment: here it is: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B95IHWEJsTuUUXduNzVkcUhlOVE

Comment: one solution is to convert excel to image and then convert it to pdf format, have you tried it?

Comment: I did it, I used smartXLS library. Thank you

Comment: what imports do I need in this example?

Comment: @MariaKarpikova you need Apache poi dependency,please download from maven center